# Page section indicators for vertical scrolling

Tags: scrolling, pagination, indicator

[image: One-page landing page displaying page indicators]

Can anyone let me know what the technical UX/UI name is for the indicators on the right-hand side.I've tried googling a bunch of variations but can't find a definitive answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It's sometimes referred to as a [vertical swiper](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-with-fullpagejs--cms-24215), or a fullscreen responsive (vertical) carousel.

Here's a library: **[fullpage.js](https://s.codepen.io/tutsplus/debug/VvZXMP#secondSection)**

And another one: [Swiper demos](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.WbXoMNOGNE4).

**[Pagepiling.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js)**